# MySQL REGEXP to find find single letter followed by a dot in email

Tags: mysql, regex

I have about 20,000 email addresses in my contacts database.  It was mass spammed once and I have a good number of emails in there that are structured like this:

a.surname111111@fakemail.com

I was to remove these in MySQL.  What's the best way to do this in MYSQL REGEXP? All emails will be a single letter followed by a surname and then 6 numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, take a look on this : http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-regexp-function.php or this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html and let us know what you try and where it fails

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
SELECT *   
FROM table   
WHERE email REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{6}@\S+\\.com$';
```